# link button using html5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button which allows me to go to a link entered in an input filed.
So this is what I did but it does not work.

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="link">
link : <input type="text" id="link">
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="self.location.href = 'docuement.getElementById('link').value'"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do?

Comment: `document.getElementById` instead of `docuement.getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use a string literal, get rid of the `'` from around the value you assign to `self.location.href`.
2. Spell `document` correctly

---

You should avoid using `self` as well, it is an unnecessary level of indirection.

Comment: I correct the expression but it is not working I get page not found

Comment: Then, presumably, the page you are typing in does not exist.

Comment: for example I want to go to google so in the text box I type www.google.com. I am looking for a solution that makes able to visit a website that I typed in the textbox.

Comment: `www.google.com` isn't the URL to Google. It's a relative URI. If you want to go to Google then you need to use an absolute URI (which would include the scheme) or one relative to the scheme (which would start with `//`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="location.href = document.getElementById('link').value"/>
```

Things fixed:

- fix spelling of `document`
- unquote the expression to be evaluated
- don't bother with `self`